# Accessing private variables and functions of angular service with decorator

Tags: angularjs

We are trying to use decorator to override existing code inorder to make sure the actual code is not changed.

However, we are able to override functions from a service which are declared using this. If a service contains private functions like function example(), I am unable to override.

Can you please help me provide an option how to read functions and variables which are not declared using "this"

Please find the plunker example --

```
var upstream = angular.module('thirdParty', []);

http://plnkr.co/edit/QQh5ljTvIb1p8tTYXicn?p=preview
```

From the above example, getContent is accessible and getContent1 is not accessible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are not accessible outside of their function scopes in JavaScript. Every private function/variable should be exposed as method/property to be available in outer scopes.

Use underscore naming convention for private properties/methods to distinguish them from public ones:

```
this._privateMethod = () => { ... };
```